# Recognize the Jinjia template delimiters

Tags: flask, emacs, jinja2

I am reading the [JinJia2 Template Engine](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#builtin-filters) and make notes with org.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC html
{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
#+END_SRC
```

When use html as src tag, delimiters of variable and control structure of the JinJia  are not highlighted.

Only the js's delimiters of `<<>>` is highlighted.

How could enable org to recognize the  JinJia template delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your text editor. There are Jinja2 color plugins for some and there are no for another. For instance, if you use Sublime or TextMate you can install `Jinja2` plugin:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jinja2

It also supports mix of both Jinja2 and HTML syntax.